# Why is Semantic-Ui Popup not Functioning?

Tags: php, jquery, css, laravel, semantic-ui

I am working on a Laravel project. I included a SemanticUI popup but it doesn't work and I get a javascript error:

> Popup: The target or popup you specified does not exist on the page

I used a view for the popup code called `popup.blade.php` and I included it in my Laravel index page.

**Popup:**

```html
<div class="ui fluid popup bottom left transition hidden" style="top: 551.634px; left: 0.994324px; bottom: auto; right: auto; width: 614.659px;">
  <div class="ui four column relaxed divided grid">
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Fabrics</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Cashmere</a>
        <a class="item">Linen</a>
        <a class="item">Cotton</a>
        <a class="item">Viscose</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.grid-cell').popup({
    inline: true,
    hoverable: true,
    popup: '.special.popup',
    position: 'bottom left',
    delay: {
      show: 300,
      hide: 800
    }
  });
});
```

**Index:**

```html
<div class="grid-calendar">

  <div class="row calendar-week-header">
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Monday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Tuesday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Wednesday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Thursday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Friday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Saturday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span class="hd">Sunday</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row calendar-week">
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell " style="background-color: #dddada;">
      <div>
        <div><span>1</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>2</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>3</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>4</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row calendar-week">
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>5</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>6</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>7</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>8</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>9</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>10</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>11</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row calendar-week">
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>12</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>13</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>14</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>15</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>16</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>17</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>18</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row calendar-week">
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>19</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>20</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>21</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>22</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>23</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>24</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>25</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row calendar-week">
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>26</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>27</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>28</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>29</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>30</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell">
      <div>
        <div><span>31</span></div>
      </div>
    </div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are selecting the dom elements that have `grid-cell` in their css class, but you don't have any element that has this css class.

Comment: i do have i will share the code now

Comment: Please provide the code necessary to reproduce the problem

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: okay and thank you for your efforts

Comment: You target `.special.popup`, but there is no element in your HTML with those classes.